# Looking For IDE Color schemes designed specifically for programmers

Tags: eclipse, vim, ide, colors, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for color schemes designed specifically for programmers that can be used by many of the popular IDEs. Recently I've discovered [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). It's supposed to reduce eye-fatigue and after using it for a while i must say it's true. Although, I really don't like solarized's colors.

When I switched back to my old colors they were too damned bright. I was quite astonished by the effect the solarized colors had on my eyes.

I'm wondering if there are other themes designed with such a precision for wide range of IDEs (and even terminal colors!).

Comment: Would you narrow this down to a specific question? From what you've written it's a discussion question, not a question to solve a particular problem. Do you want to know what the color ranges are in Vim, Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc and how to change them? Are you asking for a history of color ranges in these IDEs? I'm confused.

Comment: Why is "belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com" no longer in the off-topic options for voting to close? :/

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134636/update-migration-path-list-for-non-moderators/134642#134642.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I'm looking for other scientifically-prepared color-schemes for use in any IDE.

Comment: I'd prefer to encourage the original author to edit the post and ask a focused help question, if indeed there is one, rather than just vote to close.

Comment: @seller That doesn't sound like just putting colors into the IDE, but more how does the IDE call those colors, and/or how to install them. I suggest editing your original post's title and body to reflect this, like How do I install a scientifically designed color scheme and configure Vim, Emacs, Visual Studio, Eclipse and so on to use that color scheme.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, sorry but you don't understand me. I'm looking for a coloor-schemes build specially for programmers not how to put it in IDE (which I can do myself).

Answer (score 2):

Another popular theme that you can check is [zenburn](http://slinky.imukuppi.org/zenburnpage/). You can find that theme for any popular IDE.